# Google groups replies to group email, not the sender

Tags: google-groups

I created a few groups so that we can have customer send an email to a general email address and several us can see/respond to the email. However, when I click 'reply' on any email that is sent to the group email address, it sets the group email as the "to:" field instead of the person that sent the email.

I've tried updating the group advanced settings (settings > email options > post replies dropdown), but nothing seems to have changed. Is there something I can do so that when someone emails me I can click reply to reply to them?

Answer (score 1):

I chatted with Google support about this question, and although the representative didn't have a clue which "Post replies" setting I was supposed to pick to achieve this goal, "Users decide where their replies are sent" works exactly as I intended.
To clarify.
The behavior with this setting *(when I reply-all in a third-party email client at which I have configured my organization email address to receive a copy of messages sent to my group address)* is that **both the group address and the original author's address appear in the "To" field**.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert (I only came on here to find an answer to my newbie Google Groups question myself), but I did notice earlier today that in the "Permissions -> Posting Permissions" menu, there is an item "Reply to author", which can take different settings, so it might be worth checking that is set to "All members of the group" also?

Answer (score 0):

this is not working for me. I have tried this setting and 'reply' and 'reply all' both just send to the group! very frustrating!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/153150)

Answer (score -1):

This was helpful, the solution has changed a bit in newer Google Workplace renditions, the setting is as follows GROUP SETTINGS > POST REPLIES TO > SENDER CHOOSES RECEPIENT.

After changing this setting you will reply to the sender with reply or to the sender and the group with reply all.